# Installing Tensorflow 1.4

Tags: python, tensorflow

Any idea how to install Tensorflow-gpu version 1.4 on Windows 10? I've looked everywhere and cannot seem to figure it out. I'm trying to run Neural Networks on my GPU using Tensorflow, Keras, and Cuda 8.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before installing tensorflow, you will need to make sure that you have CUDA installed on your machine (this will only work if you have an NVIDIA GPU). You will also need [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn).
Once you have these installed, you can install it with `pip install tensorflow==1.4.0`.
For more details, see [this tensorflow.org tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/install/install_windows#requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support).

Comment: Does not work "No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.4.0"    Looks like something broke recently. I have installed tf this way so many times

Comment: This does not work anymore. It says "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0"

Comment: you need python version 3.6 then you will be able to install it